# Javascript Geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, return

I'm trying to do some things with geolocation. I want to get back the geolocation latitude and longitude in one variable as array. It doesn't work. I think the first line in the code is the problem. Is it possible to get the value like that (with return)?

```
startingPoint = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess);

function onGeoSuccess(position) {
    start['lat'] = position.coords.latitude;
    start['lng'] = position.coords.longitude;
    return start;
}
```

Is there a better solution? I don't want to execute other code in the onGeoSuccess, I want to return the value back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Check if Geolocation is supported or not and do code like this

```
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)//check for support
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that. But my question is, can I do something like this on line 5 in your code: mypos = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostion(showPosiiton); ?